# Jquery mobile: Select menus events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile site and i need to do an ajax call when an user close a select menu. i can't find the right event (something to know when the user close the select menu).
can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blur event would be your best option in this case.

```
$("#mylist").blur(function(e){
//do stuff
});
```

Comment: great, it works!! it's easier than I thought  Thank you so much!!